# Elasticsearch-curator configuration misunderstanding while implementing data retention strategy

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I have to implement data retention policy for Elasticsearch. The next actions should be performed:

- indexes that are older than 30 days should be removed; age is
  inferred from index name (indices are named according to pattern `logstash-YYYY.MM.DD`).
- oldest indexes should be removed if a disk usage threshold has been
  exceeded.

It turns out that **Curator** does exactly what i need, but as stated [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/curator-tending-your-time-series-indices):

> Please note that you cannot combine delete by space with any of the other Curator options.

My question is why can't one combine the options? And are there any way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: The documentation says `"delete indices in excess of some number of gigabytes (starting with the oldest)"`. So, first you issue the delete by space command and then the one that deletes the indices older than 30 days. For the first command curator will delete indices starting with the oldest so that it frees space. If in the remaining indices you still have some that are older than 30 days, the second command will delete those, as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: You *can* combine filters now with Curator 4, which allows for filter chaining by way of a YAML "action" file: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/actionfile.html